# Slapd won't start via service

Tags: email, ubuntu-16.04, slapd

Doing sudo service slapd start throws an error:

> -- Unit slapd.service has begun starting up. 
>   Apr 08 08:47:31 mail slapd[31144]:  * Starting OpenLDAP slapd  Apr 08
>   08:47:32 mail slapd[31149]: @(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd  (Ubuntu) (May 30
>   2017 19:20:53)
>   $buildd@lgw01-18:/build/openldap-JXEADB/openldap-2.4.42+dfsg/debian/build/se
>   Apr 08 08:47:32 mail slapd[31149]: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free 
>   Apr 08 08:47:32 mail slapd[31144]:    ...fail! 
>   Apr 08 08:47:32 mail systemd[1]: slapd.service: Control process exited, 
>   code=exited status=1 
>   Apr 08 08:47:32 mail systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB:
>   OpenLDAP standalone server (Lightweight Directory Access Protoco
>   -- Subject: Unit slapd.service has failed
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
>
> ### -- Unit slapd.service has failed.
>
> -- The result is failed. 
>   Apr 08 08:47:32 mail systemd[1]: slapd.service: Unit entered failed state. 
>   Apr 08 08:47:32 mail systemd[1]: slapd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

I did check directory permissions. Fine.
Starting sudo -u openldap slapd -d 1 is working fine, no errors thrown.

Any ideas why it won't start? The journalctl output is not helpful what exactly the error is.

Comment: Did you try to use your own credentials when starting as a service?

Comment: No I didn't yet. Going to try now

Comment: After changing user and adopting file ownerships in /etc/ldap the service still won't start, throwing eaddr already in use - which is not, so I am on the hunt for a sock file with wrong ownership

Comment: Did it another way, logged into another user, slapd -d 1 runs fine